# ssh error : kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset

Tags: ssh, headless, hotspot

I am new to Pi and using the command line.

I am trying to set up my Pi headless connected to my iPhone hotspot, I have downloaded the Raspberry Pi Imager on to SD card and used it to enable SSH and set the Wi-Fi I want it to connect to.

I can see it's connected to my hotspot, but when I try to ssh into it I get this error and since I am quite new to this I am not sure what it means.

```
C:\Users\Bea>ssh pi@170.20.10.5 -p 22
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset

C:\Users\Bea>ssh -v pi@170.20.10.5 -p 22
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 170.20.10.5 [170.20.10.5] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Bea/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
```

I know there is some questions similar to this on here but I did not really understand the answers as everyone is using sudo to edit the host allowed and denied but how can I do this if I am headless and cannot ssh into the Pi?

Hopefully this has provided enough information but I can edit the question if more is needed.